# what is the elegant way to replace string without gsub?

Tags: ruby, string, replace, gsub

I have some dynamic strings, which have an `X` character. `X` can appear continuously or scattered though the string.  I want to replace those `X` with `#`.

For example, `abXXcX12XX`. I want `ab#c#12#`. That means multiple contiguous `X` have to be replaced by only one `#` and if only one `X`, then also by a single `#`.

I tried:

```
s = "aXX123Xc56XXX"
s.squeeze('X').gsub('X','#') # => "a#123#c56#"
```

Any elegant way or direct approach to do the same operation ?

Comment: This is not a question about elegance, it is actually a question about correctness.  The problem with use `squeeze` is that it will squeeze any kind of character, not just the `X`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson That was my typo.. I fixed it..

Comment: Because you're not using a regex with `gsub`, you're losing a needed trait of `gsub` that'd let you remove `squeeze` entirely. As several of the answers showed, using `/X+/` will gobble consecutive `'X'` characters, replacing them with a single `'#'`.

Answer (score 12):

I will do using [`String#tr_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-tr_s) as below :

> *Processes a copy of str as described under `String#tr`, then removes duplicate characters in regions that were affected by the translation.*

```
s = "aXX123Xc56XXX"
s.tr_s('X','#') # => "a#123#c56#"
```

Comment: @theTinMan its `tr_s` not `tr` and its available even in 1.9.3

Comment: I had @the's reaction when I first saw your answer.  Being unfamiliar with `tr_s`, my brain latched on `tr` and raised a red flag.  It was only when I checked the docs for `String#tr` did I notice `tr_s` right below.

Comment: Interesting. When I clicked the link, Firefox landed on `tr` and didn't scroll to `tr_s`. Yes, `tr_s` is appropriate and works nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you wouldn't use gsub here?
Regexes seem to work pretty well:

```
"aXX123Xc56XXX".gsub(/X+/, "#")
=> "a#123#c56#"
```

The reason this works is that `/X+/` will match **one or more** of the `X` character, so multiple `X` in a row will generate only one match and be replaced by one `#`.

Comment: Because the OP ruled out `gsub` in the title. I agree it's the best way to handle it. You should explain why that works better though.

Comment: Yes, the reason I wrote this answer is that it was simpler and more elegant than what the OP said, and the OP did not give a reason for not allowing gsub. I agree that the answer with `tr_s` is even better too!

Answer (score 1):

```
 pry(main)> "aXX123Xc56XXX".gsub(/X+/, "#")
=> "a#123#c56#"
```

Comment: The OP said it can't use `gsub`. Using `gsub(/X+/,...` is the right way to do it though. You might want to explain your code though; Throwing out code without an explanation doesn't really help. Instead teach why it's the way to do something.

Comment: @theTinMan the OP is looking for a more elegant way of not using `squeeze` and `gsub`, after posting, someone had beat me to explanation for the same piece of code, so why do I need to reiterate the obvious

Answer (score 1):

While both `gsub` and `tr_s` will accomplish the task, here's the compelling reason to use `tr_s`:

```
require 'fruity'

STRING = 'aXX123Xc56XXX' * 1000

compare do
  using_tr_s { STRING.tr_s('X', '#') }
  using_gsub { STRING.gsub(/X+/, '#') }
end
```

Which, after running on my laptop, results in:

```
Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 1 second.
using_tr_s is faster than using_gsub by 5x ± 0.1
```

The regular expression engine has seen a lot of speedups, but it'll still be beat for non-anchored lookups. If there was a way to tell it to start at the start or end of the string we'd see it speed up greatly, and, for some search/replace actions, I've seen it outrun everything else. The pattern used is critical; Poorly written ones cripple the engine, so be careful what you use.